# Palindrome Program avoiding spaces, punctuation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a palindrome program using javascript that will show if a string is palindrome or not by **TRUE** or **FALSE** even if the string has punctuation and spaces(ex- madam, i'm adam). But everytime I put a string I only get **TRUE** no matter what the string is. Here is my code,

```
function isPalindrome (str) {
    var nopunctuation = str.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
    var nospaces = nopunctuation.replace(/\s/g,"");
    var finalstring = nospaces;

    var len = finalstring.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < Math.floor(finalstring/2); i++ ) {
        if (finalstring[i] !== finalstring[len - 1 - i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;    
}

console.log(isPalindrome("madam i'm adam"));
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Point to be noted, I'm not allowed to use any built-in or library function. Your help would be much appreciable. Tnx.

Comment: To reverse it, use `finalstring.split('').reverse().join('')` then compare. e.g. `String.prototype.isPalindrome = function(){var a = this.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]|\s/g,'').toLowerCase();return a == a.split('').reverse().join('');}`

Comment: Oh, sorry to mention that before but I can't use any built-in or library function for this problem. I've to do it in a raw way if you know what I'm saying.

Comment: @akz, nope not working.

Comment: `.replace` is a "built-in or library function".

Comment: @BradChristie, Will figure out a way around.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fwrdce5j/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the "for" clause, replace "Math.floor(finalstring/2)" by "Math.floor(len/2)"

Also, you might want to improve your punctuation removal so that it also removes apostrophes, for instance.

So your code would become the following:

```
function isPalindrome (str) {
  var nopunctuation = str.replace(/\W/g,"");
  var nospaces = nopunctuation.replace(/\s/g,"");
  var finalstring = nospaces;

  var len = finalstring.length;
  for ( var i = 0; i < Math.floor(len/2); i++ ) {
    if (finalstring[i] !== finalstring[len - 1 - i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;    
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. But I'm confused about RegEx. To be honest, I copied the regex part only since I'm confused about how to add, edit. So i don't know how to add apostrophes. I'll be really thakful if u can just show me how to add it. Tnx.

Comment: Just edited my answer to provide the full solution. In order to add apostrophes, you could have gotten away replacing your regex by the following one:
    /['\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/
(notice the newly added apostrophe at the beginning of the character class, i.e. after the opening square bracket)

But it's just as simple to use the predefined non-word-character class: \W (which matches any character NOT part of the \w class, which itself contains a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the underscore)

Comment: TnQ for your awesome explanation.