# How do I check if a phrase is a palindrome in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have written the code below to check if a word is a palindrome, but I would like to know how I would check if a phrase is one too.

```
function palindromeCheck(string) {
    const check = string.split('').reverse().join('');
    return string === check;
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between a word and a phrase? Whitespace? Punctuation marks? If so, you just need to first remove whitespace and punctuation and then apply your palindrome check.

Comment: What strings are you testing with? `palindromeCheck("a bad dab a")` returns `true`

Comment: What is the error with this code?

Comment: The problem I'm having is that if I run "race car", it will return false. I suppose the answer is to remove the whitespace, but I am unsure how to do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229850/javascript-check-for-palindrome-spaces-punctuation-included, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250163/palindrome-program-avoiding-spaces-punctuation-in-javascript,

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the whitespace.

```
function palindromeCheck(string) {
  string = string.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  const check = string.trim().split('').reverse().join('');
  return string === check;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `+` in the regexp? What's the purpose of the `trim`? Also, instead of `split`, you can use `[...string]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is grossly inefficient. There are about a hundred palindrome solutions here on SO, which can you search for easily, but just for your reference here's one:

```
function palindrome(s) {
  for (var i = 0, j = s.length-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    if (!/\w/.test(s[i])) i++;
    else if (!/\w/.test(s[j])) j--;
    else if (s[i].toLowerCase() !== s[j].toLowerCase()) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```